# Inject ViewModel property as ValueConverter

Tags: wpf

All ValueConverter examples I have found used Resources to create ValueConverter instance. But my ValueConverter uses some dependencies which are resolved by IoC framework. So I would like to set Binding Converter property to some property of my ViewModel which is accessible through DataContext. I tried to do it but got an exception telling I can't bind anything to Converter property of binding.

Comment: Why not just convert the value in your DataContext, then bind to the converted value?

Comment: @Rachel, becuase ValueConverter creates WriteableBitmap from Points which are passed from ViewModel. I want to keep UI part (WriteableBitmap) in view level

Comment: You should keep Converters on the View level too, since that's what they're for - converting data from one type to another for the UI. If you have a single parameter you need to convert, use a `IValueConverter`, however if you have multiple values that are needed for the conversion then use an `IMultiValueConverter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind `Binding.Converter` as it is not a dependency property, but you can make the converter inherit from `DependencyObject` and declare [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) on that instead, then you can bind those.

Note however that you might need to jump some hoops to get what you want as you will not be able to bind to the `DataContext`. You probably cannot use ElementName either because the converter will have no name-scope. One common workaround is to target an object with the right DataContext using `Binding.Source` with [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx). Make sure not to declare to instantiate the converter inside the visual tree of the targeted object or `x:Reference` will throw cyclical dependency errors (the targeted object's `Resources` are fine).